# Use SQLExpress with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I would like to check if it's possible to install Sharepoint with SQL Server Express edition? 
I have SQL Server Express which is freeware. Can I use it for SharePoint installation and development?

Comment: Possible solution: https://www.netometer.com/blog/?p=1442

Answer (score 1):

sql express supports only 4 GB of data to be stored in it. This could cause issues with SharePoint installation.